# when ionic cordova run android is runned, tranformclasses error shows on the command prompt

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

i am currently developing a ionic 5 hybrid app with cordova but, when I try to deploy it on my android phone or emulator, it keeps giving me this error on my command prompt.
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
I have tried numerous amounts of ways, removing android from the project, clean the project and updating my npms but, everything just does not seem to work. can I get some help?
Below are my specifications i have on my laptop
Ionic:

Ionic CLI : 6.11.8

Utility:

cordova-res : 0.15.1
native-run  : 1.0.0

System:

NodeJS : v12.16.2
npm    : 6.14.4
OS     : Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Haha turns out I had to install admob into my app, it is solved now.